# Map numbered values into separate objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm attempting to map an array from this:

```
[
  {
    "person_1": "jim",
    "person_2": "bob"
  }
]
```

to this:

```
people: [
  {
    "person": "jim"
  },
  {
    "person": "bob"
  }
]
```

Right now, my map method is to select each of the values, but it seems inefficient:

```js
const ogArray = [{
  "person_1": "jim",
  "person_2": "bob"
}]
const newArray = ogArray.map((person) => {
  return {
    people: [{
        person: person.person_1
      },
      {
        person: person.person_2
      }
    ]
  }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

The above method works but it's not DRY and I wish I could select each object with a wildcard like person_*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding the properties, use `Object.values()` to loop over the object's values.

```js
const ogArray = [{
  "person_1": "jim",
  "person_2": "bob"
}];

const newArray = ogArray.map(og => ({
  people: Object.values(og).map(value => ({
    person: value
  }))
}));

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to use `ogArray.map` like OP did in their original example instead of `ogArray[0]` - it may contain multiple objects.

Comment: You're right, I've fixed it.

Comment: thanks @Barmar I'll accept the answer but I simplified my question too much for this answer to be applicable for my much more complex array.